# Universal Yes or No Bash Script Filling in the blanks

Tags: bash

I've solved this before but cannot find the solution at this time and Google just give the simple Yes or No selection we all know and love.

I want my script to contain two functions: One for defaultYes and one defaultNo.
My script contain multiple 10+ Yes or No questions.

Whenever I meet [Y/n] or [y/N] I want to call the function.

The important part of the script. **Mostly need to fill in the gaps, but if you have a better solution go ahead!**

```
mc_install() {
  as_user "cd $MCPATH"
  if [ ! -f $SERVICE ] > /dev/null ; then
        echo "$SERVICE already exist. Do you want to update?[y/N]"

   defaultNo
   update

  else
    echo "$SERVICE does not exist. Do you want to download?[Y/n]"

   defaultYes
   install

fi
}

defaultYes() {

            *) 
                true
                ;;
            [nN][oO]|[nN])
                false
                ;;
            esac
}

defaultNo() {

            [yY][eE][sS]|[yY]) 
                true
                ;;
            *)
                false
                ;;
            esac
}
```

Yes I wrote this almost by myself, just a little help from a online ShellCheck :) I wish to learn programming for real sometime...